# Cypher query for finding out content and connectedness as security measure

Tags: memgraphdb

I have a node that represents a computer infected with malware. I want to see if other computers (based on log files) have had some interaction with the infected computer. I have already transferred and mapped log files into the Memgraph database.

How would Cypher query look for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic cypher code that you can use for this scenario would be:

```
MATCH p1=(n:Node1)-[*]->(m:Node2), p2=(n)-[*]->(m), (n)-[r]->(f:FraudulantActivity)
WHERE p1!=p2
RETURN nodes(p1)+nodes(p2)
```

This Cypher query looks for different paths `p1` and `p2` between node named `n` and node named `m` and returns such nodes on those different paths. Those nodes could be part of some malicious actions.